# VSCODE - (launch.json) What do I change to instantly run the php file instead of just launching localhost/

Tags: php, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

```
{
        "name": "Launch built-in PHP CLI server",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "-S",
            "localhost:9003",
            "-t",
            "./"
        ],
        "port": 9003,
        "serverReadyAction": {
            "action": "openExternally"
        }
```

New to working with php and currently have this in `launch.json`. Is there any workaround to instantly open the php file I am working on?

When running, it initializes into `localhost:9003/` without going right into the file and I have to manually enter the filename (`localhost:9003/test.php` etc.) to access the file which does work, but I have to manually do it every time it launches.